# If $g(x)=\int_4^x(t-t^5)^3dt$, what is $g'(x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I have the problem, if $g(x)=\int_4^x(t-t^5)^3dt$, what is $g'(x)$? I've tried to do this myself, but I got the wrong answer.

**My Steps:**

$$\int^x_4(t-t^5)(t-t^5)(t-t^5)dt$$

$$=\int^x_4(t^2-2t^6+t^{25})(t-t^5)dt$$

$$=\int^x_4(t^3-t^{10}-2t^{7}-2t^{30}+t^{26}-t^{125})dt$$

$$F(x)-F(4)=f(x)-0=f(x)$$

$$f(x)=x^3-x^{10}-2x^7-2x^{30}+x^{26}-x^{125}$$

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: $(t-t^5)(t-t^5)=t^2-2t^6+t^{10}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $F$ an antiderivative of $(t-t^5)^3$, then $g(x)=F(x)-F(4)$ and thus $g’(x)=F’(x)=(x-x^5)^3$

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{\mathrm d ~~}{\mathrm dx}\int_a^x g(t)\mathrm d t = g(x)$$

Comment: Not for $g(x)=\begin{cases}0&x\neq a\\1&x=a\end{cases}$.

Answer (score 0):

Use Newton Leibniz rule here:
If$ g(x)= \int_{\phi(x)}^{\psi(x)}f(t)dt$
Then $g'(x)=f(\psi(x))(\psi '(x))-f(\phi(x))(\phi '(x))$. Here, $f(t)=(t-t^5)^3$, $\psi(x)=x$, $\phi(x)=4$,so $g'(x)$ comes out to be $(x-x^5)^3$

Comment: Corrected it!..